# how angular2 app can call jsp page

Tags: json, angular, jsp, typescript

I am trying to integrate my Angular2 + Java web app with another one which consists of many JSPs (and doesn't have any Web Services).

What is a right way of calling non visual JSP page from Angular?   I assume the call passes JS object (or JSON) and returns another object or JSON (which might have some status, error code, maybe include input object with some modifications).

Should response be processed as observable?

Any code samples?

TIA,
Oleg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP run on server side in addition to html, css and js. it would be most appropriate to say that your angular web app calls a servlet. For instance, you may have an angular web login page whereby the servlet will do the authentication procedures and return a json string denoting a successful or unsuccessful authentication which can be parsed in your angular web app. For any remote calls in angular use angular http api, please refer to these two links

https://angular.io/guide/http
https://angular.io/api/http/Http

An example to get you going is as per below

If your servlet url is annotated as follows

```
@WebServlet("/login")
```

//in your servlet you can use java libraries like json writer or google gson to build your json object and then send it using for instance response.getWriter().

in your angular web app, you can call the servlet as follows:

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/testapp/login')
            .map((res: Response) => {
                //this.result will contain the results of the authentication process
                this.result = res.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

hope its enough to get you going. the angular link will help you understand more.

Ashley